# How to choice the ingress controller version for aliyun cloud server

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

when check the [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#prerequisite-generic-deployment-command) install page, there is no loadBalance version for aliyun cloud. How should I alternative choice for it?

Comment: have you seen [this tutorial](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/routing-applications-in-kubernetes-with-nginx-ingress_594719)?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in my comment you can find a guide regarding this topic in the [official blog](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/routing-applications-in-kubernetes-with-nginx-ingress_594719):

> In this article, we will show you how to set up and configure
>   nginx-ingress to route applications in Kubernetes on Alibaba Cloud.

And you would be especially interested in this part:

> **Loadbalancer**: Exposes the service externally using a cloud provider's
>   load balancer. `NodePort` and `ClusterIP` services, to which the external
>   load balancer will route, are automatically created.

I hope it helps.